# salesforce1 hyperlink is not working second time

Tags: salesforce1-app, navigation

I have 1 publisher action on account object that open a VisualForce Page,
content of visualforce page is.

```
<a href="javascript:sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{! account.Id}','detail');"> hyperlink </a>
```

navigate to account detail page.

its working only once,but not second time I don't know why.
please help with solution.

Comment: Have you tried executing this from the desktop (using the /one/one.app URL) to see if there are any JavaScript errors?

Comment: yes i tested using one/one.app,it not giving any javacript error at console

Comment: hi @BobBuzzard have you run this code at your side?

Comment: Yes, I use this in a number of places without any problems.

Comment: @user3559241 did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use navigateToURL(objectId) method.
example:

```
<a href='javascript:sforce.one.navigateToURL(<<objectId>>);'> hyperlink </a>
```

Note:<> is placeholder for recordId within quote.